# Want to find fields in a column that start with certain letters

Tags: business-objects

I'm looking to find a way fields that only start with certain letters

Example: Within the "Postcode" column on the report, I want to show only postcodes that start with "CF"

My best guess would be to create an object that marks these down as a number, but I don't know how to identify them.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What reporting solution are you using?  What version?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Webi.
You can create variable, wich helds only symbols you are interested in. In your example it would be:
f=left([Postcode];2)
Then restrict table in the report by filter. And add values you want to filter list.